# php exec() function and different hosts

Tags: php, exec, command-line-interface

I have a script that executes a file in a couple of directories down which looks like this:

```
exec("php-cli $file_path > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &"); //php command-line
```

This works on most hosts but some hosts don't like it and it doesn't run, without generating any error.

For the hosts that this fails on, i use

```
exec("php $file_path > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &"); //notice the -cli is gone
```

Which works fine.

$file_path is the full path to the file being executed /home/blah/path/blah.php

How can i make this uniform so it works on all servers (unix at least)

**EDIT****

Well, I'm doing it this way, it is (most likely) not the correct way but it works.

Instead of just using php-cli or php, i use both so if one fails, the other goes through. Either the php is running as cgi or cli and one of these will catch, and since there is no output, there would be no error either.

```
exec("php-cli $file_path > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
exec("php $file_path > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

Unless you know a better solution please let me know. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Why not just use `php` on all hosts? Should work on all hosts.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't for some odd reason.

Comment: No error at all in log file. i can check the apache error log and see if anything there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function php_exec($file_path) {
    if (!($binary = which(array('php', 'php5', 'php-cli', 'php-cgi'))))
        return false;

    return exec("$binary $file_path > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
}

function which($binaries) {
    if (!($path = getenv('PATH')) && !($path = getenv('Path')))
        return false;

    $arr = preg_split('/[:;]/', $path);

    foreach ($arr as $p) {
        foreach ($binaries as $b) {
            if (file_exists("$p/$b"))
                return "$p/$b";
        }
    }   

    return false;
}

var_dump(php_exec('test.php'));
```

Explanation:
On most systems the PHP binary is called php, php5, php-cli or php-cgi. which() function checks the standard path (both *nix and windows have environment variable called PATH/Path) for each of those names and if it find a file with such name, it will return it.

The PATH variable's format is: `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin` for *nix (bash), and `C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\;` for windows, so that's why I use preg_split('/[:;]/')

This solution is better than yours, because php_exec() will return `false` if it can't find a valid php binary. In your solution there's no way to know if the script execution failed.

Comment: Thanks, Would you mind adding some comments to it as to explain what i have to do?

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now, specially if I look at the which() function first. If you are interested, I have a very big project coming up and I could use a good php programmer. Is there a way to exchange contact info here?

Answer (score 1):

Simple question perhaps, but does `php-cli` exist on all the hosts? I assume the reason its failing silently is because you're telling it to be redirecting everything away.

```
exec("php $file_path > /some/writable/path/output.log 2>/some/writable/path/error.log &");
```

Comment: That's a good question, I need to look into that, but the question is that why the regular exec() function is not working on hosts that do have the php-cli ?

Comment: Instead of redirecting the output to nul, how about redirecting it to a file instead? Might give you something to check.

Comment: The exc function can be disabled through a setting in php.ini, some web hosts might not like you running scripts from php

Comment: @Filype you should probably post that as an answer, as it doesn't seem to have anything to do with my answer, i.e. whether the php-cli exists or not.

Comment: The exec() function is enabled on all hosts that i'm testing on.

Comment: It skips right past the exec() function and finished the rest of the calls on that script :(

Comment: So nothing in the log file that you redirected the output of the command to?

Comment: the error log is empty, the ouput log is no help as it just outputs the test file contet`Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<h2> Run </h2>`

Comment: Well, you can't say "no help at all" - surely it proves that the exec is being run, that the php is executing your script, and that php is outputting what it should! So the real question now becomes "What makes you say it's *not* working, because your PHP is outputting what it should"...

Comment: It's not, It's outputing the content of the file that the function is being executed in. the $file-path content is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Then perhaps your $file-path is wrong. print that out just before your exec.

Comment: If the file path is wrong, so why would php-cli work with the wrong file path? It's really weird.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the PHP-CLI binary is compiled. On most systems the executable is named just 'php' and I guess that the hosts that have 'php-cli' have it compiled by hand, while most of the others have it installed via the OS package manager.

You have two options to work around that and make it "universal":

1. On each of the servers, add an alias for one of them where needed, or make a symlink to the PHP executable somewhere (e.g. in your home directory).
2. Prior to executing, check which one of them exists (usually, it should be located in /usr/bin/) and set it to a variable.

Comment: The second option is interesting. How can i check for it on multiple systems, nix windows,... as the path would change on pretty much all of them?

Comment: Check in the paths listed in `$_SERVER['PATH']`.