# how can I execute a php command line script from a web call

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php exec() function and different hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431938/php-exec-function-and-different-hosts)

I have a web app that when save button is clicked it makes an ajax call to save.php. I want to be able to make a command line call for a command line only php script to run from inside of the save.php file.

ex.

```
some code to make a db call and update db

exec('PathToPHP /path/to/file/refresh.php');
```

I have tried this and it does not work.

does anyone have a good solution?

thanks

Comment: Did you turn on error_reporting? Did you check the webservers error.log? What's the output of exec? After adding `2>/dev/stdout` perhaps? Why don't you turn your cmdline script into an include file?

Comment: I am getting a sh:/path/to/php: not found in the error logs

Comment: Well great. Now that you found the problem, *you* can solve it.

Comment: actually its more of a problem. that is the correct path I ran it directly from CL and it worked fine. any reason why it would do this when running from exec()

Comment: Permissions, suexec, SELinux, jailroot, ... many possibilities.

Comment: it may be a permission issue. if the script calling exec(...) is being called from the web, you may want to check that your web user (usually www-data for apache servers) has permissions to execute your refresh.php file. hopefully this is of some help to you

Answer (score 0):

If this process takes a long time and the client doesn't wait for it to finish and navigates away while this is running apache will kill the thread handling this. That I'm sure of.  Haven't tested this under fastcgi mode under nginx but I'm pretty sure this will be the case too.